# Why is there an ASUS folder in C:\ProgramData with my complete Windows folder structure mirrored?

Tags: windows-8.1

I used WindirStat to clean up some space on my SSD. I stumbled across a folder named `C:\ProgramData\ASUS` which has a majority of my Windows folder structure mirrored and is therefore ~15 GB big.
When trying to delete files or folders from it, there is a strange error message about not having the rights to do that, despite acting as administrator.

Is this folder important? It seems like some kind of caching shenanigans, I'd rather have the space on the SSD free.

Comment: What ASUS software do you have installed?  That directory would only be used by ASUS OEM software.  Without specifics with regards to what it contains it is difficult to determine how you should delete it.  Just because you are an Administrator does not mean the Administrator uses has the proper permissions on the folder in question.

Comment: I have nothing particular installed that is ASUS related... My mainboard is ASRock, I really can't think of anything. Nothing shows up in Programs. Tough to debug, there is also nothing really coming up on Google, which is rarely a good sign.

Comment: Could it be a ASUS backup? And system cache is to speed up stuff, but since we don't know what it is exactly, **don't** delete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since resolved the 'problem', by retaking ownership of the whole folder:

```
right click -> properties -> security -> advanced -> set new owner recursively
```

and deleting it completely.
I felt super safe doing this, because my whole system has various backup routines in place. I mirror the SSD once in a while, the Windows File History is turned on and I don't rely on my system as data store in general.

No negative repercussions whatsoever. 15GB more space on my SSD and a dubious ASUS copy of all my files is gone. Good thing! Just wanted to add this here.